# Develop applications for Windows Compact

Tags: c#, embedded, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded-8

I have an Windows Embedded Compact v8.00 [device](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/products/6av2124-0qc02-0ax1/simatic-hmi-tp1500-comfort?pid=1044897&mlfb=6AV2124-0QC02-0AX1&mfn=ps&lc=en-WW) installed with build 6247. FYI - This device is an Siemens HMI.

Now I'm looking for the right way to develop applications for this version of Windows. I started trying with Visual Studio 2008, so I build a very simple application with just a useless textbox. After copying the executable to the device I start tried to run the test applications but nothing happens.

After searching the web I found out it's better to install Visual Studio 2015 PRO with an application builder from [Microsoft's website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=38819).

Is this the right way to do? What else does I need to know when developing applications for Windows Compact 2013?

Comment: We need to know what kind of applications you’re building. Line-of-business? Data-entry? Multimedia kiosk? Internet-of-things? Are you intending to use XAML-for-CE?

Comment: The objective of the application is to capture usb-sensor-data with a C# application and send a modified value to a PLC. The only requirement for the application is that it's compatible with the DLL for the sensor and the DLL for the connection to the PLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create applications for Windows Embedded Compact 2013 you need VS2013 or VS2015 professional with the Application Builder plugin and a valid SDK installed on your PC.
If you develop managed apps you also need to check in the .NET runtime is already part of the image or find a way to deploy and install it permanently on your device (the way to do this may change depending on the device configuration, registry type etc.)